# How should I secure spindles on a baserail without a groove?

Tags: stairs

I would like to replace a single piece metal spindle with wooden spindles, however, the metal is just screwed into the baserail, which does not have a groove.  So I cannot follow [instructions like these](http://www.wonkeedonkeerichardburbidge.co.uk/how-to-fit-staircase-spindles/#step3) where the spindles are kept in place with 'fillets' while they are being pinned.  The top handrail does have a groove on the underside, so that will be fine, but what do I do about the baserail?

Edit: added a couple of pictures.  Note how ugly it is, and how it isn't actually even attached to the handrail!

[image: Current spindle] [image: Baserail]

Answer (score 2):

The plough (or plow, so I have been told it is called) under the hand rail makes for a simple, secure way to attach a baluster  to the rail. If the cut is a little off, the cut is hidden by the sides and the fillets.

For the bottom fit, it only needs to be cut neatly to fit the bottom plate, if that is what you have and secure in place with a few 4D (1 1/2") or 6D (2") finish nails or a couple of trim head screws after pilot holes are drilled.

Since there is most likely a hole where the metal baluster used to be, each of the 2 nails will go on either side of the drilled hole since the wood baluster will cover the old hole. If a long enough trim head screw is used, say 2 1/4"-3" long you may only need the one screw to hold it at the bottom. The longer screw will span through the old hole and grab wood on the other side.

Comment: Thanks. I added some images. I guess you can see there are no holes, apart from the screw holes.  If I put a couple of finishing nails in, I guess they'll hardly be visible.

Comment: +1 Note that the current metal balusters do not meet building code in may locales.  And if you replace with balusters only at the screw holes, it will be even less compliant. Most rules require a gap no wider than 4 inches or 100mm. This is meant to prevent a child from getting its head stuck between balusters (or even slipping through completely).

Comment: Before the picture was posted I took it for granted the balusters were code. Yes if he just put them in at the screw locations.... boy that would be no way compliant....